# How to connect Apache Druid and Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I tried to connect apache druid to apache superset but I cannot find the druid databases option in the sources window so if anyone can help, please.

i tried to use pydruid to connect but I get this problem:
sqlalchemy: druid://127.0.0.1:8082/druid/v2/sql/sales_1

DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:8082
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:8082 "POST /druid/v2/sql/sales_1 HTTP/1.1" 404 0
Unexpected error (pydruid.db.exceptions.ProgrammingError) Unknown error (Unknown):
[SQL: SELECT 1]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
ERROR:superset.views.core:Unexpected error (pydruid.db.exceptions.ProgrammingError) Unknown error (Unknown):
[SQL: SELECT 1]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jun/2020 17:31:46] "POST /superset/testconn HTTP/1.1" 400

Comment: try to show us what you have tries so that you get suitable help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `pydruid` error messages are slightly cryptic, I believe Eugenia's answer is correct, i.e. your URI is incorrect, and it should end in `/druid/v2/sql`. For reference, my local Druid cluster is connected to `druid://uid:pwd@localhost:8888/druid/v2/sql`.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably is the legacy druid connector that now is deprecated. Now, in Superset you need to install the druid driver

```
pip install pydruid
```

and then use as any database connection with URI :

```
druid://<User>:<password>@<Host>:<Port-default-9088>/druid/v2/sql
```

Comment: thanks i already installed pydruid but i still have the same problem,, i get DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:8082
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:8082 "POST /druid/v2/sql/sales_1 HTTP/1.1" 404 0
Unexpected error (pydruid.db.exceptions.ProgrammingError) Unknown error (Unknown): 
[SQL: SELECT 1]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)